# Can CefAddWebPluginPath(); implement for CefSharp.WinForms.Example ? How?

Tags: java, winforms, plugins, cefsharp

I'm trying to swap Java Versions in MyBrowser, I found CefAddWebPluginPath() "..\packages\cef.sdk.3.1750.1738\CEF\include\cef_web_plugin.h" but dont know it's possible to call and how. Java of MyBrowser 's always  stick with the highest version set in Register.
I'm using Win 7 x64, using VS2013 compile  CefSharp.WinForms.Example
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is solved with CefSharp version 43, only version 43, different version not work